# react-native-paper-dates date picker not displaying

Tags: css, react-native

I am trying to include a date picker on my website. The date picker does not appear on the screen unless the display width is less than 650. [Screen width 1920 - not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eNck.png). When it does appear it looks very squashed, the numbers are overlaying each other. It appears on the far left of the screen. I think the start of the flex box? [Screen width 650 - showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS75D.png) I am not confident in React Native or CSS so I've just been changing everything to see what it does. I have tried changing the padding, margin, width, minWidth of the DatePickerModal as well as changing the CSS of the View that contains the DatePicker.

**Import:**

```
import { DatePickerModal } from "react-native-paper-dates";
```

**Return that contains the  of the datepicker**

```
  return (
    <View style={styles.test}>
      <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
        <DatePickerModal
          // locale={'en'} optional, default: automatic
          mode="single"
          visible={true}
          onDismiss={onDismissSingle}
          date={date}
          onConfirm={onConfirmSingle}
          // style={styles.defaultPicker}
          // height={500}
          // width={500}
          // minWidth={1000}
          // padding={100}
          // margin={100}
          // alignSelf={"center"}
        />
      </PaperProvider>
      <Button
        color="#ffba00"
        title="cancel"
        onPress={() => {
          console.log("open");
          setshowAll(true);
          setShow(false);
          setOpen(false);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

**Style of the View showing what I've tried.**

```
test: {
    minWidth: 1000,
    alignContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    alignSelf: "center",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    width: 600,
    position: "absolute",
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
  },
```

I have also tried removing the PaperProvider and it did not change anything.
I am using Expo to run the website on Chrome. It is built with React Native.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question here; I've been having the very same issue with `react-native-paper-dates`.

I haven't been able to solve your problem above, but I suspect it is because the css for DatePickerModal is not being imported.

I've managed to solve what appears to be a similar issue (the same issue?) with `react-datepicker`.

### Without css

Here is the import for `react-datepicker` without the css:

```
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
```

And the resulting [incorrect layout is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZpvk.png); you can see the similar layout to your problem above - it is in a vertical line, overlapping, etc.

### With css

Here is the import for `react-datepicker` with the css:

```
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
```

And the resulting [correct layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3hNX.png); you can see the layout is correct (or at least very close.

### Conclusion

I suspect the css for DatePickerModal is not being imported from `react-native-paper-dates`.